# C# UserControl as message box

Tags: c#, messagebox

i want to create a new message box from UserControl class as below code, but when i call show method then it does not show. i am not understand what problem in it.. please help me..
in this UserControl their is only one button as OK, label as MSG, image as ICON.
if button will click then control will dispose. 
sorry for poor english....

```
 partial class CMessage : UserControl
    {
        public static string Ok;
        public static string Warning;
        public static string Error;
        public static string Information;
        public CMessage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    public static DialogResult Show(string title, string msg){
        CMessage form = new CMessage();
        form.Show();
        return form.ReturnValue(title,msg);
    }

    public DialogResult ReturnValue(string title, string msg) {

        ICON.Image = icon(title).ToBitmap();
        MSG.Text = title;
        MSG.Text +='\n'+ msg;
        this.Visible=true;
        this.Show();
        return DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private Icon icon(string title)
    {
        if (title == CMessage.Ok)
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Application;
        if (title == CMessage.Error)
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Error;
        if (title == CMessage.Warning)
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Warning;
        return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information;
    }

    public void BT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need a UserControl, I think it should be a Form (winform) a UserControl should be inside a Form....

Comment: Displaying a dialog requires ShowDialog(), not Show().  This went wrong primarily by deriving from UserControl instead of Form.  A user control is always a child control that's embedded inside its parent.  Only a toplevel window can be a dialog.  A class derived from Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or even inherit from it if you really need to.

The built in message box should be suitable for what you require.